# Please help to check my ans and correct me if i am wrong

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Show that there does not exist a rational number such that x^2=6.
Is sqrt2 + sqrt3 a rational number ?

My answer : 
Let x = (a/b)in lowest term. 
(a/b)^2 = 6
a^2=6b^2
--> a is multiple of 3 so let a=3n
(3n)^2 = 6b^2
9n^2 = 6b^2
3n^2 = 2b^2
-->2b^2 is a multiple of 3 , so b also multiple of 3 
Conclusion : Since both a and b share same factor so x could not be rational.

Assume sqrt2 + sqrt3 is rational 
r^2 = (sqrt2 + sqrt3 )^2
(2 sqrt6) + 5 = r^2
sqrt 6 =( r^2 -5)/2
Conclusion: Since sqrt6 is irrational,so (r^2-5)/2 also irrational which bring a cotradiction . Hence , sqrt2 +sqrt3 is irrational .

OR 
Assume sqrt2 is irrational,
sqrt2 = a/b in lowest term
square both side , a^2 = 2b^2
--> a is multiple of 2 so let a =2n
(2n)^2 = 2b^2
4n^2=2b^2
b^2 = 2n^2
-->so b is also multiple of 2
Since a and b has same factor so sqrt2 cannot be rational

sqrt 3 = a/b
a^2 = 3b^2
-->a is a multiple of 3, so let a =3n
(3n)^2 = 3b^2
9n^2 = 3b^2
b^2= 3n^2
-->b is also multiple of 3 
CONCLUSION: since a and b share the same factor hence sqrt 3 not rational

Conclusion: Since sqrt2 and sqrt3 is not rational hence sqrt2 + sqrt3 is also not rational

For the second part i don't know which answer is correct , so i write both

Comment: It hurst the eyes to read such a thing. Please do learn MathJax to write mathematics in this site.

Comment: It's OK you didn't know about MathJax, since you seem to be new here. Welcome to Math SE, and I'll recommend you to go through an easy tutorial of formatting Math on this website. [Click here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct. That is, you proved correctly that $\sqrt6$ is irrational and that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is irrational too.

The second part (your other proof of the fact that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is irrational) is wrong. The sum of two irrational numbers may well be rational. Take $\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$, for instance.

Comment: so can i know how to solve the second part ?

Comment: @lindseychan I don't understand your question. You have already proved that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is irrational (by proving that its square is irrational). I just wrote that your other proof is wrong.